# Building a relational database using nodej s and sqlite3

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, promise, electron

I'm building an electron app and using sqlite3 for storing and fetching the data locally.

Problem - There are two tables table1 and table2, first I have to insert a record in table1 and then want to use the insertedId of table1 in table2 to build a relationship

The unsuccessful code -

```
var name = document.getElementsById("name").value;
var date = document.getElementsById("date").value;
var type = document.getElementsById("type").value;
var db = new sqlite3.Database('././user.db');

db.serialize(function() {
   var insertId = 0;

   db.run("INSERT INTO table1 (name,date) VALUES ('" + name + "','" + date + "')", function(err) {
      if (err) {
         return console.log(err.message);
      }

      // get the last insert id
      insertId = `${this.lastID}`;
      console.log(insertId);
   });
   var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO applicants (patentId,type) VALUES ('" + insertId + "','" + type + "')");
   stmt.run();
   stmt.finalize();


   db.close();
   //all database Queries and system closed here
});
```

When I'm running this code then 0 is inserted in table2 as table1ID and the real insertedID is printed in console log after this I think this is some asynchronous nature, I'm new to JavaScript.

Comment: Move your three statements `var stmt... stmt.finalize()` one row up, inside the `db.run` callback. The way this is now, `insertId` is assigned in the future, and JavaScript has no time machine. As a rule of thumb, all info obtained from async is only available inside the async callback (or promise continuation).

Comment: i'm getting an error in console : "Uncaught Error: SQLITE_MISUSE: Database handle is closed". if i move these statements.

Comment: Ah... missed the `db.close()`. Same thing – move it into the callback.

Comment: It helped!!! thanks a lot @Amadan for your help...

Comment: @Amadan write an answer?